# How to make <tr> tag visible next to input using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to show `tr` tag after `onblur` event on `input`tag. I have made function but it is not working. What I want when user blur `input` then only first .check `tr` from blured input should visible. Here is example [code](http://jsfiddle.net/5JWRX/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('input').blur(function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').nextAll('tr').filter(function(){
            return $(this).index()==0
        })
    })
})
</script>
<style>
    .check{ display:none}
</style>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td><input /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="check">
        <td>hiiii</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="check">
        <td>hiiii</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="check">
        <td>hiiii</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just get next `tr.check` via selector, without having to filter it:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mishik/5JWRX/5/)

```
$('input').blur(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').nextAll('tr.check').first().show();
});
```

Comment: It is working with first input. It should work with second and third input also

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $('input').blur(function () {
        $(this).parents('tr').nextAll('tr.check').slice(0,1).show();
    })
})
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/pThCB/)